# Euclidean geometry; concyclic points and parallelism problem.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics

Given an acute triangle $ABC$ with a tangent to its circle at point $B$. If $E$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$ and $F$ is the foot of the perpendicular of $C$ to the tangent line. Show that $EF$ is parallel to $AB$.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider arc $AB$, then angle $ACB$ is equal to angle $ABD$
[image]